# Angular coefficient of the straight line tangent to the parabola at one of its points: alternative proof

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, alternative-proof

Let be $P_0(x_0,y_0)\in\mathcal P : \, y=ax^2+bx+c$. We know that the $m$ angular coefficient of the straight line tangent $t$ in $P_0$ is:

$$m=2ax_0+b \tag 1$$

To find the $(1)$ I before consider the system,

$$\begin{cases} y=ax^2+bx+c & \\ y-y_0=m(x-x_0)\end{cases} \iff ax^2+(b-m)x+c+mx_0-y_0=0 \tag 2$$

If $P_0\in\mathcal P$ we have $x=x_0$ it is a zero of the $(2)$; being $t$ is tangent to $\mathcal P$ in $P_0$

$$2x_0=x_0+x_0=-\frac{b-m}{a} \iff m=2ax_0+b$$

Without the use of the derivatives that would be immediate, is there a more immediate alternative proof?

Comment: It is "known" of parabolas that the chord through points $A$ and $B$ is parallel to the tangent at $P$, where the axis-parallel line through $P$ meets the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. Therefore, taking $A=(x_0-k, \ldots)$, $B=(x_0+k,\ldots)$ for any $k\neq0$, you can simply calculate the slope of the line $AB$. However, that's not really any more "immediate" if you aren't already familiar with the parabola property. There's a bit of "conservation of proof energy" at play here. The amount of effort required to establish the geometry is about equal to the amount required to solve your system.

Comment: @Blue The reason of my question is very simple: to increase my knowledges...for to help my next students...Unfortunately, and I write this with great sadness, the level of Italian students in Mathematics and Physics has decreased dramatically. I must always look for the best ways without any calculations and with all sincerity even if the proof was two lines they do not even remember about that. Every answer is always welcome.

Comment: @Blue Whenever you want, I'll wait for your answer.